# I am trying to make a python program that converts a decimal number to a hexadecimal one, but when I run it it gives me a format conversion error

Tags: python, arrays, type-conversion

Here is my code

```
acHexaDeci = ['0']*8
iCont = 0
iReminder = 0
iDecimal = input("Type a decimal number: ")

while(iDecimal != 0):
    iReminder = iDecimal % 16

    if(iReminder < 10):
        acHexaDeci[iCont] = iReminder + 48
        iCont+=1
    else:
        acHexaDeci[iCont] = iReminder + 55
        iCont+=1
    iDecimal = iDecimal / 16

    i = iCont - 1
    while(i >= 0):
        print((acHexaDeci[i]), end="")
        i = i - 1
```

I know that the array is specified as a string and the rest of the variables are integers, but the array must be a string since I am saving a hexadecimal value.

Here is the error message:

```
Type a decimal number: 4287
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\VS-Code\ASIX1-M3\python\p9e2.py", line 21, in <module>
    iReminder = iDecimal % 16
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: It seems like you should be converting the user input from a string to a number.

Comment: replace 4th line of your code with this `iDecimal = int(input("Type a decimal number: "))`.